# Return an object of one class in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a scenario where there are two classes say ClassA and ClassB with methods MethodA and MethodB respectively. I have to write generic method that returns the object instances of the above classes depending on the condition of some integer variable say x. When I try the code below, I get an error that says "Cannot implicitly convert ClassA to T" or "Cannot implicitly convert ClassB to T"

```
public ClassA
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        //method implementation
    }
}

public ClassB
{
    public void MethodB()
    {
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

Generic method as

```
public T MethodGeneric<T>()
{
    int x;
    ClassA objectA = new ClassA();
    ClassB objectB = new ClassB();

    if(x==2)
    {
        return objectA;
    }
    else
    {
        return objectB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give ClassA and B a commom base class or interface, and restrict T to that type.

Comment: - or just cast: "return (T)objectA;" etc.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Then when someone says `MethodGeneric<SomeOtherClass>` they get your namesake back as response.

Comment: I think I see your point, but it is not at all obvious from the example what the purpose of the type argument is.

Comment: The technical problem you face is an intended behavior of an object oriented language. I would advice you to create two different factory methods, probably even factory classes for construction of ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Agreed. Your name made the joke too easy, and I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `T` is not `ClassA` nor `ClassB`.

You could attempt to handle this via casting, like so:

```
public static T MethodGeneric<T>() where T : class
{
    int x = 2;
    ClassA objectA = new ClassA();
    ClassB objectB = new ClassB();

    if (x == 2)
    {
        return objectA as T;
    }
    else
    {
        return objectB as T;
    }
}
```

However, this will not protect you if somebody calls `MethodGeneric<ClassC>()`, other than returning `null` in that case.

You could make this safer if you have `ClassA` and `ClassB` both derive from the same base class or interface, as you could then put a generic constraint in place that would reduce the chance of error.  However, this would still not be a completely safe way of working, as the generics wouldn't be appropriate.  It might be better to have an interface implemented by both classes (ie: `IClassBase`) and then not use generics, but return the interface:

```
public IClassBase CreateInstance()
{
    //... 
         return objectA; // This will work fine, provided ClassA implements IClassBase
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can cast that way `return (T)objectA` anyway. You need to push it to object first `return (T)(object)objectA;` but I agree with the rest.

Comment: If he wants to be able to call type specific methods by name on the original types this is all for naught. Would need one more layer of abstraction.

Comment: @asawyer Yeah - it's fairly pointless unless there is a defined contract in place - like an interface which can be used.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Regarding the interface example, would you consider an interfaces or an abstract base w/ virtual overrides more appropriate? I'm sometimes confused on when to use one over the other.

Comment: @asawyer It depends - I'd use a base class if the types are more of an "is-a" type of relationship, and an interface if the shared info is more behavior (ie: "acts-as").

Comment: @asawyer Think of an interface as defining a component, the internals of which are entirely black-boxed. It takes an A and returns a B. Inheriting from a base class allows code re-use for common methods, etc... so is more appropriate when the implementation of 2 types overlap

Answer (score 0):

From your [this double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918863/generic-method-with-return-type-as-object?rq=1) which is closed, you're close. You're passing `object` as type argument, which will return again the same `T` that is `object` in your case. That's why you can't use the properties defined on `ClassA` objects. Instead you should pass the required type like `ClassB` or `ClassC`. May be this:

```
public T getObject<T>(int i) where T : ClassA
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        return objB as T;
    }
    else
    {
        ClassC objC = new ClassC();
        return objC as T;
    }
}

public static void main()
{
    var obj = getObject<ClassB>(5); //which wont work anyway since i == 5 !!
    obj.aValue = 20;
    obj.bValue = 30;
    //obj.cValue = 40; this wont work since obj is of type ClassB

    //or 

    var obj = getObject<ClassC>(5);
    obj.aValue = 20;
    //obj.bValue = 30; this wont work since obj is of type ClassC now
    obj.cValue = 40; 
}
```

I'm not sure why you're checking variable `int i` to decide what's the type that should be returned. That's not a true use of generics. A genuine use of generics might look like:

```
public T getObject<T>(int i) where T : ClassA
{
    return new T(); //without the use of int i
}
```

If `int i` is what decides which object to be returned back, then why use generics at all? You may very well do:

```
public ClassA getObject(int i)
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        return objB;
    }
    else
    {
        ClassC objC = new ClassC();
        return objC;
    }
}

public static void main()
{
    var obj = getObject(5);
    if (obj is ClassB)
    {
        obj.aValue = 20;
        obj.bValue = 30;
        //obj.cValue = 40; this wont work since obj is of type ClassB
    }
    //or 

    var obj = getObject(5);
    if (obj is ClassC)
    {
        obj.aValue = 20;
        //obj.bValue = 30; this wont work since obj is of type ClassC
        obj.cValue = 40; 
    }
}
```

but the catch is you have to check the type from caller side (Main).

And if you want to assign properties `bValue` and `cValue` on both `ClassB` and `ClassC` objects then you should write these properties in `ClassA`.

Furthermore you're only using a `get` accessor, you need `set` as well to assign values.