# Generic method with return type as object

Tags: c#, generics, object, return

```
ClassA
{
        int a;
        public int aValue
        {
            get { return a; }
        }
}

ClassB : ClassA
{
      int b;
        public int bValue
        {
            get { return b; }
        }
}

ClassC : ClassA
{
      int c;
        public int cValue
        {
            get { return c; }
        }
}

public void getObject(int i) 
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
         objB.aValue = 20;
         objB.bValue = 30;
         Console.Writeline(objB.aValue);
         Console.Writeline(objB.bValue);
    }
    else
    {
        ClassC objC = new ClassC();
        objC.aValue = 20;
        objC.cValue = 40;
        Console.Writeline(objC.aValue);
        Console.Writeline(objC.cValue);
    }
}
```

Instead I would like to create generic method that returns an object such that:

```
public T getObject<T>(int i) where T : class
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
         return objB as T;
    }
    else
    {
        ClassC objC = new ClassC();
        return objC as T;
    }
}

public static void main()
{
    Object obj = getObject<Object>(5);
    obj.aValue = 20;
    obj.bValue = 30;
    obj.cValue = 40;
    Console.Writeline(obj.aValue);
    Console.Writeline(obj.bValue);
    Console.Writeline(obj.cValue);
}
```

In this case obj = objC so bValue = 30 and cValue = 40 should happen. But I am not able to do it this way. 
                                                                                           This is my third attempt. I hope I am clear at least this time.

Comment: It seems like maybe you should ask for the best approach to your problem, instead of how to cram your square peg into a round hole. 1) No one can see why generics should come into play here at all. 2) Should there be some kind of common interface or base class for your two classes? 3) If you're trying to set one or the other set of variables, that is going to have to be added to the same logic that determines which class to return, so why have the classes in the first place?

Comment: This is not what generics are used for, I suggest that you re-read some tutorials about generics.

Comment: This is my third attempt. I hope I am clear at least this time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem may be the way you are asking your question...

You would use a where clause in the generic constraint to constrain it..

I am not sure why you would want to force a boxed object for a generic method...

Comment: +1, that advice was also given in a previous incarnation of this question.